# This may be a naive question, but how do I interface with the iPad/iPhone's bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, ipad

How can I send bluetooth packets to and from these things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont have direct access to the Bluetooth hardware. You can use the GameKit framework to setup and manage Bluetooth connections